# How do I call a js prototype method from within the constructor function?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I've read the similar questions on SO and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I can't call the prototype method from within the constructor method.
I get: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'afterLoad'

```
var FiltersByDivision = function () {
   $(document).on('afterLoad', this.afterLoad());
};

FiltersByDivision.prototype.afterLoad = function (){
   console.log('afterLoad');
}

function OpenOrders() {
  Widget.call(this);
  FiltersByDivision.call(this);
  this.widgetEndpoint = '/xxxxx';
}

OpenOrders.prototype = Object.create(Widget.prototype);
OpenOrders.prototype.constructor = OpenOrders;
```

Comment: Are you creating a new `OpenOrders` object with `new`?  `var x = new OpenOrders();`?  And, why are you calling `FiltersByDivision` which you do not inherit from?

Comment: Yes, with new as in var x = new OpenOrders();

Comment: Where is any code that inherits from `FiltersByDivision`?  Your `OpenOrders` object will not have any methods from the `FiltersByDivision` prototype because you never did anything to inherit from that object or to add those methods to your object.

Comment: Also note that you're currently binding the `afterload` event to the _result of calling_ `this.afterLoad()` (currently `undefined`), not to the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with this code:

1. You aren't inheriting from FiltersByDivision so thus an `OpenOrders` object does not have any `FiltersByDivision` methods.  That's the reason why there is no `afterLoad` method.
2. `$(document).on('afterLoad', this.afterLoad());` will execute `this.afterLoad()` immediately and pass it's return result as the event handler (which is not what you want).  After you fix item 1, perhaps, you want `$(document).on('afterLoad', this.afterLoad.bind(this));`

There are many possible structures here.  If `FiltersByDivision` is a separate object, then perhaps `OpenOrders` should just have one of those objects in its instance data like this (though if all it is doing is setting up an event handler, I'm not sure why it is a separate type of object):

```
var FiltersByDivision = function () {
   $(document).on('afterLoad', this.afterLoad.bind(this));
};

FiltersByDivision.prototype.afterLoad = function (){
   console.log('afterLoad');
}

function OpenOrders() {
    Widget.call(this);
    this.filter = new FiltersByDivision();
    this.widgetEndpoint = '/xxxxx';
}

OpenOrders.prototype = Object.create(Widget.prototype);
OpenOrders.prototype.constructor = OpenOrders;
```

Comment: Do you know anywhere that explains #1? I've been surprisingly unlucky in  searching for a good explanation of prototype inheritance.

Comment: @NeilKempin - we'd need to understand more about what you're really trying to do as there are several different approaches depending upon the specific needs and structure/organization of objects and inheritance.  See one such idea I added to my answer.

Comment: @NeilKempin you could try the link posted in my answer. If anything is unclear there you can comment on that question

Answer (score 0):

As jsfriend already pointed out is that afterLoad   is not on ObjectOrders prototype. Doing a OtherConstructor.call does not inherit that constuctors     prototype but initializes instance variables.

The value of this is the invoking object so the declaration of the function doesn't define its value but how you invoke it. You could use closures:

```
var FiltersByDivision = function () 
   var me = this;
   $(document).on('afterLoad', function(){
      me.afterLoad();
    });
 };
```

More info on this, prototype and closures can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Comment: still doesnt work Uncaught TypeError: Object #<OpenOrders> has no method 'afterLoad'